# IllegalArgumentException converter-bean MessageConverter does not implement InboundMessageConverter

Tags: jms, jdeveloper

I need help with my OEP application. I'm trying to convert a jms-inbound message by using my own converter bean. But when deploying I’m getting the following exception.

> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-171"
>   org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Error in context
>   lifecycle initialization; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: converter-bean MessageConverter
>   does not implement InboundMessageConverter    at
>   com.bea.wlevs.spring.ApplicationContextLifecycle.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationContextLifecycle.java:146)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.java:235)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:358)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:136)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: converter-bean MessageConverter
>   does not implement InboundMessageConverter    at
>   com.bea.wlevs.adapters.jms.InboundJmsAdapter.initialize(InboundJmsAdapter.java:122)
>     at
>   com.bea.wlevs.adapters.jms.InboundJmsAdapter.beforeResume(InboundJmsAdapter.java:228)
>     at
>   com.bea.wlevs.adapters.jms.InboundJmsAdapter$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fc18e7ee.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   com.bea.wlevs.ede.impl.EventManagerAccessorProxy.invoke(EventManagerAccessorProxy.java:30)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   com.bea.wlevs.ede.impl.EventBeanProxy.invoke(EventBeanProxy.java:38)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
>     at
>   com.bea.wlevs.adapters.jms.InboundJmsAdapter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fbc02af8.beforeResume()
>     at
>   com.bea.wlevs.spring.ActivationBeanPostProcessor.preProcessBeforeContextResume(ActivationBeanPostProcessor.java:27)
>     at
>   com.bea.wlevs.spring.DeferredBeanPostProcessor.beforeResume(DeferredBeanPostProcessor.java:33)
>     at
>   com.bea.wlevs.spring.ApplicationContextLifecycle.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationContextLifecycle.java:120)
>     ... 9 more

My class is as follows...

```
import com.bea.wlevs.adapters.jms.api.InboundMessageConverter; import com.bea.wlevs.adapters.jms.api.MessageConverterException; import com.bea.wlevs.adapters.jms.api.OutboundMessageConverter; import javax.jms.JMSException; import javax.jms.Message; import javax.jms.Session; import javax.jms.TextMessage; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public class MessageConverter implements InboundMessageConverter, OutboundMessageConverter{
    public List<TestEvent> convert(Message message) throws MessageConverterException, JMSException {
        TestEvent event = new TestEvent();
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        event.setString_1(textMessage.getText());
        List<TestEvent> events = new ArrayList<TestEvent>(1);
        events.add(event);
        return events;
    }
    public List<Message> convert(Session session, Object inputEvent) throws MessageConverterException, JMSException {
        TestEvent event = (TestEvent) inputEvent;
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Text message: " + event.getString_1());
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        messages.add(message);
        return messages;
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add "com.bea.wlevs.adapters.jms.api" in the "Import-Package" section of the MANIFEST.MF file?

HTH